# How to find batch element in Websphere commerce error

Tags: sql, db2, websphere, batch-processing, websphere-8

When I am running buildindex in my Websphere application, I have this error in buildindex log:

```
[2021/05/10 15:41:57:590 GMT] I Data import pre-processing completed in 0.389 seconds for table TI_CAT_EXTENDED_41060.
[2021/05/10 15:41:57:591 GMT] I /opt/IBM/WebSphere/CommerceServer80/instances/auth/search/pre-processConfig/MC_41060/DB2/wc-dataimport-preprocess-catentry-metainf.xml
[2021/05/10 15:41:57:591 GMT] I 
Table name:     TI_X_CATENT_META_INF_410600
Fetch size:     500
Batch size:     500
[2021/05/10 15:41:58:048 GMT] I Error for batch element #415: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.19.77
[2021/05/10 15:41:58:048 GMT] I SQL: SELECT CATENTRY_ID, TITLE, TITLE_KEYWORDS, SHORT_DESC, SHORT_DESC_KEYWORDS, LONG_DESC, LONG_DESC_KEYWORDS, LOCALE FROM X_CATENT_META_INF WHERE STORE_ID = 41006
[2021/05/10 15:41:58:087 GMT] I 
The program exiting with exit code: 1. 
Data import pre-processing was unsuccessful. An unrecoverable error has occurred.

[2021/05/10 15:41:58:091 GMT] E com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.preprocess.DataImportPreProcessorMain:handleExecutionException Exception message: CWFDIH0002: An SQL exception was caught. The following error occurred: [jcc][t4][102][10040][4.19.77] Batch failure.  The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member of the batch.
Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements. ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null., stack trace: com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.exception.DataImportSystemException: CWFDIH0002: An SQL exception was caught. The following error occurred: [jcc][t4][102][10040][4.19.77] Batch failure.  The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member of the batch.
Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements. ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null.
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.preprocess.DataImportPreProcessorMain.processDataConfig(DataImportPreProcessorMain.java:1515)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.preprocess.DataImportPreProcessorMain.execute(DataImportPreProcessorMain.java:1331)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.preprocess.DataImportPreProcessorMain.main(DataImportPreProcessorMain.java:534)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:280)
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.BatchUpdateException: [jcc][t4][102][10040][4.19.77] Batch failure.  The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member of the batch.
Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements. ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b4.a(b4.java:475)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Agent.endBatchedReadChain(Agent.java:414)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ki.a(ki.java:5342)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ki.c(ki.java:4929)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ki.executeBatch(ki.java:3045)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.preprocess.AbstractDataPreProcessor.populateTable(AbstractDataPreProcessor.java:373)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.preprocess.StaticAttributeDataPreProcessor.process(StaticAttributeDataPreProcessor.java:461)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.preprocess.DataImportPreProcessorMain.processDataConfig(DataImportPreProcessorMain.java:1482)
    ... 7 more
```

The exception seems to be clear, but I can't identify what is the element #415 in batch. Even the log doesn't helps, because it doesn't point to another more detailed log. Do you have any suggestion for find it?

Comment: See https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/pre-processing-search-index-fails-error-code-302-sqlstate22001-b1a97b21d6e4f2ed852579a700718266

Comment: I'm not commerce expert, but error - SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001 - \means `INPUT VARIABLE OR PARAMETER IS INVALID OR TOO LARGE` and then failing query `WHERE STORE_ID = 41006` . So I'd guess that `STORE_ID` is incorrect. Try this query via sql tool to see if it produces any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of user @mao, I have [followed this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/pre-processing-search-index-fails-error-code-302-sqlstate22001-b1a97b21d6e4f2ed852579a700718266)

> The failing table first must be identified. Enable more detailed tracing for di-preprocess:
>
> Navigate to :
>
> WC_installdir/instances/instance_name/xml/config/dataimport
>
> and open the logging.properties file. Find all instances of INFO and
> change it to FINEST. Optionally increase the size of the log file and
> the number of historical log files while editing this file.

Thanks to this suggestion, I had re-run the buildindex process, and found that solr was wrongly grouping fields from original table, thus generating a too long field for the destination, and generating the error.